# Show that if $R$ and $S$ are Noetherian rings then so is $R\underset{T}{\times}S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider homomorphisms of rings,

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\vspace{-10pt}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,auto]
\node (A) at (0,0) {$R$};
\node (B) at (1.5,0) {$T$};
\node (C) at (1.5,1.5) {$S$};
\node (D) at (0,1.5) {$R\times S$};

\path[->]
(C) edge node[right] {$\psi$} (B)
(A) edge node[above] {$\varphi$} (B)
;

\path[dashed,->]
(D) edge node[right] {$\pi_1$} (A)
(D) edge node[above] {$\pi_2$} (C)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
\end{figure}

(Sorry for the code above. I don't know how to produce the diagram on stackexchange.)

The fiber product of $R$ and $S$ over $T$ is the subring $R\underset{T}{\times}S=\{(r,s)|\varphi(r)=\psi(s)\}$ of $R\times S$. Assume $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are surjective. Show that if $R$ and $S$ are Noetherian rings then so is $R\underset{T}{\times}S$.

If $R,S$ are Noetherian rings, then there exists a surjective homomorphism. Is it enough to show that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are also surjective?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51697/fibre-product-is-noetherian

Comment: But isn't it trivial that $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are surjective?

Comment: It's not trivial for fiber products, but now it follows from the condition that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are surjective.

Comment: Ok. Once I show that, am I done? Or is there more to show?